# What is the meaning of speed?

Tags: meaning

In Crime/Drama movie *Drugstore Cowboy*, Bob is busy injecting him and his friends with drugs,
suddenly David came to Bob's house and knock the door.
Bob terrified thought it was somebody else, started to hid the
drugs and relaxed by knowing it is David, Bob's friend, by seeing through peep hole. 
he opened the door and pointed gun with his friends on David.

> David: What are you holdin'?
>
> Bob: I ain't holdin' diddly, small fry. I was just  thinking about
>   going by your place to see if you had any **speed**.
>
> David: Yeah, well, I got some **speed**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a [street name for amphetamines](http://amphetamines.com/amphetamine-abuse/street-names-for-speed/):

> **Speed** is the powdered version of methamphetamine, usually snorted like the prescription amphetamines that are crushed into a power or injected (NSW). Speed is one of the most common terms for meth and differs from the other ways the drug can be produced: crystal (usually referred to as ice) and liquid.

[**Urban Dictionary definition of speed**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=speed).